# php variable scope in functions

Tags: php

I'm having difficulty with variable scope.  I have a function that looks up a lab value from a multidimensional array.  I want to pass the function the name of the lab and have it look it up.  The $lab I pass to the get_lab function however is not accessible to the second function used in the array_filter.  Where am I going wrong with scope?

```
function get_lab($lab){
    $result = array_filter($labs_array, function($v) { 
        return $v[1] == $lab; 
    });
    print_r($result);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare variable in `use` clause like this

```
function get_lab($lab){
    $result = array_filter($labs_array, function($v) use ($lab) { 
        return $v[1] == $lab; 
    });
    print_r($result);
}
```

Check the manual for [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass $lab to inner function..

One way is to use the use keyword

```
function get_lab($lab){
    $lab = $lab;
    $result = array_filter($labs_array, function($v) use ($lab) { 
        return $v[1] == $lab; 
    });
    print_r($result);
}
```